# es6 What makes Block-Scoped Variables different?

Tags: javascript

Looking at http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedVariables

What a difference between

`for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { let x = a[i] … }`

and

`for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { var x = a[i] … }`

I understand in example they move declaration of variables out of block

```
var i, x, y 
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
{ 
x = a[i] … 
}
```

but is there any reason for it ? why not to include declaration inside the block ? Is it a bad practice or performance hit ?

Just want to understand.

Thanks.

Comment: In the latter (using `var`), `i` is available after the `for` loop is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference is **scope**.

Before ES6, you were stuck using `var`. When using `var`, variables were defined in the scope of the enclosing function. If there is no function, then they are defined on the global object (typically `window`). This made it difficult to have two variables *named* the same, but in different scopes without running into conflicts.

`let` helps to solve this problem by allowing you to scope variables to the enclosing block, like an `if` or `for` loop.

For example, one common issue was nested `for` loops:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){ // loop 1
    console.log(i); // 0

    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){ // loop 2
    }

    console.log(i); // 4 - since i was changed by loop 2, loop 1 is now unstable and will skip
}
```

In the example above, the problem is eliminated using `let` instead - each `i` variable is scoped to it's own block.

As for any differences in performance, I can't say. If someone else knows, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 4):

Block scoped variables are simply not available outside their containing block. This is easy to illustrate with an example

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) console.info('inner loop i', i);
try {
  console.info('after loop i', i);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message)
}

for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) console.info('inner loop j', j);
console.info('after loop j', j);
```